# Errors occur when hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd is validated in the context of mycontext.xml

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, hazelcast, xsd-validation

I have this problem when my context.xml is validating hazelcast's xsd file. Other xsd files are not giving error. I am going crazy, how can I solve this issue? this is the error descripton:

> The errors below were detected when validating the file
>   "hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd" via the file "imcp-core-context.xml".  In
>   most cases these errors can be detected by validating
>   "hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that
>   errors will only occur when hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd is validated in
>   the context of imcp-core-context.xml.
>
> s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema
>   elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation' Saw "301 Moved Permanently"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd ">
```

And this is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, it is answered at here
[Hazelcast Spring integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964479/hazelcast-spring-integration-issue) very simple. it just http to https issue. Then dont forget to Validate your XML file too.